# How "Edit Online" using Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, alfresco, wss, alfresco-share

I've got a fresh install of Alfresco Community Edition, v4.2e. I'm able to use "Edit Offline" with Internet Explorer. But with other browsers, I get this message:

```
The file ... could not be opened for online editing. 
One of the following plugins required to be installed in your browser. 
For Windows: Microsoft Office 2010 
For Mac OS X: SharePoint Browser Plug-in
```

I have Office 2007.

I found this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27106 which seems like the right thing. But the installer requires a 32-bit OS.

Does anyone know:

1. If there is a plug-in that works for current Firefox and Chrome, with Office 2007, on a 32 bit OS?
2. If using Office 2010 will work?

Answer (score 0):

I've got different plugins active in FireFox, can't fouch for Chrome:

1. Microsoft Office 2010 14.0.4730.1010
2. Microsoft Office 2013 15.0.4545.1000 (used for Lync)
3. Microsoft Office 2013 15.0.4514.1000

I guess if you download these it should work fine.

Comment: where your link? Thanks

Comment: These should come when installing MS Office. If not a bit of searching should do the work.